# Galois extensions of Local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $ L / K $ be a Galois extension of local fields.

My question: why $L / K$ is necessarily of finite degree ??

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the inclusion $K\hookrightarrow L$ is continuous, so that $L$ is a topological vector space over $K$, this is true, though the condition that $L/K$ is Galois is not needed. If $V$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space over a local field $K$, then $V$ is locally compact if and only if $V$ is finite-dimensional over $K$. This is a special case of Theorem 3, No. 4, $\S 2$ from Bourbaki's *Topological Vector Spaces*.

Comment: thank you very much Keenan

Comment: I mean, we knowe explicitly what the local fields are :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis fields which are complete with  respect to a discrete valuation and have finite residue field.

Comment: @Amine That's not true actually. Take any infinite field $K$ and give it the trivial valuation--this is complete, discrete and even locally compact, but does not have finite residue field. But, what does this have to do with my comment anyways?

Comment: Dear @Alex, I think it is customary (although perhaps not universal) to assume that the topology of a local field is non-discrete. Also, I would say that proving the result above about locally compact TVS is not much harder than classifying locally compact fields.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell I agree that, by definition, local fields are non-discrete, I was just pointing out that what Amine said was incorrect as stated. Also, I would guess that the result you stated isn't much harder than the classification, but I was just saying that there is a much more explicit reason why the OP's question is easy to see.